# Capybara / Ruby / Cucumber - Making the command Expect to be highlighted in the evidence

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, cucumber, capybara

I'm generating evidences every time that I run a cucumber scenario. It is working fine, however I would like to improve it a little bit more.

My idea is highlight all the "expect" commands into the evidence to make clear the result.

I'm using a hook to generate the evidence, so I think I have to do something there.

```
After do 
    shot_file = page.save_screenshot("log/screenshot.png")
    shot_b64 = Base64.encode64(File.open(shot_file, "rb").read)
    embed(shot_b64, "image/png", "Screenshot") 
 end
```

So, when I declare a expect command I would like to see it in the evidence highlighted.

```
expect(find(".nav-a.nav-a-2.nav-truncate")).to have_content "Hello, my name"
```

Any idea guys?

Thank you very much!

Comment: is `expect` always your last step in scenario/scenario outline? (meaning before hitting the `after` hook?

Comment: yes, thats right, my expect will be always the last command..

Comment: Then get the validation element and change the style of element or css. You can execute [javascript](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#evaluate_script-instance_method)  and update the element style.

Comment: Got it, do you have an example? I've never used something like that before.. Thanks!

Comment: Let me share the js to change the style.

Comment: ohh, thank you, I really appreciate that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below javascript to highlight the border of the element before taking the screenshot.

```
element.style.border = '0.5em solid red';
```

Here is the sample video.
[image]

Comment: Just change the color and the thickness based as required.